# Jasmine - how to test functions that should only be called once (executed via a closure variable)

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I'm using a closure to ensure that something is only called once:

```
var pageDOM = (function() {
  var mounted = false

  return {
    initializePage: function() {
      if (mounted == false) {
        pageDOM.addBoxes();
        mount = true
      }
      pageDOM.otherInitProcedures();
    },
    otherFunction: function() {
    }
  }
})();
```

I'm not sure what's the right way of thinking about unit testing `pageDOM.initializePage`. Jasmine specs are run in random order, and I think it's important to keep this for testing integrity (i.e., I would NOT want to impose order). This is my spec code:

```
describe("pageDOM", function() {
  describe("initializePage", function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
      spyOn(pageDOM, "addBoxes")
      spyOn(pageDOM, "otherInitProcedures")
    })
    describe("calling initializePage first time", function() {
      beforeEach(function() {
        pageDOM.initializePage();
      })
      it("should call both functions", function() {
        expect(pageDOM.otherInitProcedures).toHaveBeenCalled()
        expect(pageDOM.addBoxes).toHaveBeenCalled()
      })
      describe("calling initializePage again", function() {
        beforeEach(function() {
          pageDOM.initializePage();
        })
        it("should only call otherInitProcedures", function() {
          expect(pageDOM.otherInitProcedures).toHaveBeenCalled()
          expect(pageDOM.addBoxes).not.toHaveBeenCalled()
        })
      })
    })
  })
})
```

The problem is that if the specs don't run in order, then both will fail. What's a way to test this, or should I even try to test this?

Answer (score 0):

I would assign the spies to variables and reset the spies in an `afterEach` hook.

Something like this (follow the !! in the comments):

```
describe("pageDOM", function() {
  describe("initializePage", function() {
    // !! initialize these variables
    let addBoxesSpy;
    let otherInitProceduresSpy;
    beforeEach(function() {
      // !! assign the variables
      addBoxesSpy = spyOn(pageDOM, "addBoxes")
      otherInitProceduresSpy = spyOn(pageDOM, "otherInitProcedures")
    })
    describe("calling initializePage first time", function() {
      beforeEach(function() {
        pageDOM.initializePage();
      })
      it("should call both functions", function() {
        expect(pageDOM.otherInitProcedures).toHaveBeenCalled()
        expect(pageDOM.addBoxes).toHaveBeenCalled()
      })
      describe("calling initializePage again", function() {
        beforeEach(function() {
          pageDOM.initializePage();
        })
        it("should only call otherInitProcedures", function() {
          expect(pageDOM.otherInitProcedures).toHaveBeenCalled()
          expect(pageDOM.addBoxes).not.toHaveBeenCalled()
        })
      })
    })

   // !! Reset the spies in an afterEach
   afterEach(() => {
     addBoxesSpy.calls.reset();
     otherInitProceduresSpy.calls.reset();
   });
  })
})
```

After resetting the calls to what you're spying on, order should not matter anymore.

Comment: this doesn't address the issue. the problem is that say the second spec is called first, since `mount` is indeed `false`, `addBoxes` will be called, so that spec fails (because it says `expect(pageDOM.addBoxes).not.toHaveBeenCalled()`) and then when the first spec runs, since `mount` is now `true`, `addBoxes` will no longer be called, so that spec also fails (because it says `expect(pageDOM.addBoxes).toHaveBeenCalled()`

Comment: Oh I see, maybe you can reset the mount variable in an afterEach. I am not sure if it is possible though.

Comment: right...... i don't think it is possible...

Answer (score 0):

So your "pageDOM" method is state full, so why use 2 times describe and set the call to "initializePage" method every time by hooking it in beforeEach, doesn't make sense. Instead you can do like this -

```
describe("pageDOM:initializePage", function() {
    describe("calling initializePage first time", function() {
      beforeEach(function() {
        spyOn(pageDOM, "addBoxes");
        spyOn(pageDOM, "otherInitProcedures");
      })
      it("should call both functions", function() {
        pageDOM.initializePage();
        expect(pageDOM.otherInitProcedures).toHaveBeenCalled()
        expect(pageDOM.addBoxes).toHaveBeenCalled()
      })
      it("should only call otherInitProcedures", function() {
        pageDOM.initializePage();
        expect(pageDOM.otherInitProcedures).toHaveBeenCalled()
        expect(pageDOM.addBoxes).not.toHaveBeenCalled()
      })
    })
  })
```

Jasmine executes it blocks within a describe sequentially and you can get the desired checks as well. [Working stackblitz link for you(ignore other testcases)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/unit-test-template-78vul5?file=src/app/app.component.spec.ts)

Comment: the link sometimes passes/sometimes fails, which is also behavior  I'm seeing... where in the docs do you see that jasmine executes it blocks sequenetially?

Answer (score 0):

To make the code more testable, I would not initiate the function immediately.

```js
var pageDOMConstructor = vfunction() {
  var mounted = false

  return {
    initializePage: function() {
      if (mounted == false) {
        pageDOM.addBoxes();
        mount = true
      }
      pageDOM.otherInitProcedures();
    },
    otherFunction: function() {
    }
  }
};

var pageDOM = pageDOMConstructor();
```

then you can test `pageDOMConstructor` easily.
To check how often something has been called you can use `toHaveBeenCalledTimes`

this is not quite complete and might need some small changes, its just to give you an idea of how to solve this:

```js
describe("pageDOMConstructor", function () {
  describe("initializePage", function () {
    // setup variable, its a let because it will be reset before every test
    let pageDom;
    beforeEach(function () {
      pageDom = pageDOMConstructor();
      spyOn(pageDOM, "addBoxes");
      spyOn(pageDOM, "otherInitProcedures");
    });
    
    it("should call both functions when calling initializePage first time", function () {
      pageDOM.initializePage();
      expect(pageDOM.otherInitProcedures).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
      expect(pageDOM.addBoxes).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });

    it("should only call otherInitProcedures when calling initializePage again", function () {
      pageDOM.initializePage();

      // you could remove these two lines because they are in the other test
      expect(pageDOM.otherInitProcedures).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
      expect(pageDOM.addBoxes).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

      pageDOM.initializePage();
      expect(pageDOM.otherInitProcedures).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
      expect(pageDOM.addBoxes).not.toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
  });
});
```

Each `it` should be treated like a separate test, and they should be completely self reliant - with some exceptions like `beforeEach`

When code is hard to test, it's often a sign that you could benefit from refactoring it a bit. I have found that testable code equals usable and flexible code in production.